# Extract timestamp of an educational video for extracting particular topics with the respective timestamp using python

Tags: python, video-streaming

I would like to inform earlier that i have not built any code for this as of yet, but have this idea, and want to know how far is this feasible?
So i have this video link: https://youtu.be/Y8xhrUa3KH4?si=7MTdlcXMlnrWggfG this is an excel video of length 52 mins that includes all the excel formula and functions, now can i create short clips of this video for each topic and store them along with their timestamps,so that if I make a call let's say for the topic vlookup, I will get the short clip of this video that only includes the vlookup.